# Injecting strings and services with Net Core default DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a Net Core 2.1 Console application where I do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();

        var fullPath = configuration.GetValue<string>("tempPath:fullPath");

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyService>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<Worker>();
        ...


public class Worker
{
    public string FullPath {get; set;}
    private readonly MyService _myService;

    public Worker(MyService myService,
        string fullpath)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        FullPath=fullpath;
    }
```

In other words, I need to inject services and configuration string in my `Worker` class in some way.

Can someone suggest me the right way to do it?

Comment: Inject configuration *objects*, not raw strings

Comment: There is `IOptions` pattern https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 2):

Just change your DI configuration to the following:

```
var fullPath = configuration.GetValue<string>("tempPath:fullPath");
serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyService>();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<Worker>(x => new Worker(x.GetRequiredService<MyService>(), fullPath));
```

Or as suggested use the `IOptions` interface to inject your configuration object into the class.

Comment: Or use configuration objects and IOption. Not my downvote, and I don't think it's justified. .NET Core already has an appropriate mechanism though

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Personally I do not like my classes taking a dependency on `IConfiguration` as that will allow you to read every configuration value. But good point on `IOptions`

Comment: While this works, it's a bit of an antipattern. There's a reason things like `services.Configure` exist.

Comment: They don't need to access IConfiguration at all. Just a strongly typed object containing those values. That object can be built from configuration values, or even explicitly created and registered

Comment: If you want to use command line verbs and options for example, the "config" object will come from the command line parser, not the Configuration middleware. The services don't have to know either way.

Comment: Imagine having 20 classes that injects at least 5 other service which they inject some other. And for just injecting a string value you configure them manually as above.